# dpkg errors when trying to install nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Trying to install nginx:

1. First:

   ```
   sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
   ```

   Result:

   Looks everything okay:

   ```
   > ## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 16.x and npm
   > ## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
   >      sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
   > ## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
   >      curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
   >      echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee
   > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
   >      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
   ```
2. Then:

   ```
   sudo apt install -y nodejs nano nginx
   ```

   Looks okay but asked to run `apt --fix-broken install`

   ```
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.18.0-6ubuntu11.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-full (< 1.18.0-6ubuntu11.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-light (< 1.18.0-6ubuntu11.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-extras (< 1.18.0-6ubuntu11.1~) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: nginx-core (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu11) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-full (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu11) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-light (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu11) but it is not going to be installed or
                     nginx-extras (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu11) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   apt --fix-broken install`
   ```

   There are errors:

   ```
   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.13.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
    trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/fs.html', which is also in package nodejs-doc 12.22.5~dfsg-5ubuntu1
   dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.13.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
   needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```

I don't know what to next, but looks nginx is not installed

Comment: Why didn't you just `apt install nginx`?

Comment: The same result on step 2

Comment: I mean before you did all of that. There was no reason to add those repos nor is there any need for `nodejs`. `nginx` is in Ubuntu's repos so all you had to do from the start was to `apt install nginx`. You can start by removing the needless Yarn repository.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were not able to even do `apt-get install nginx`. I had that problem too and, in my case, I wasn't able to even uninstall until I manually removed all the existing instances of nginx. It seems like I had previously (tried to) install nginx some day and I didn't remember and my installation was a mess. Try

```
$ whereis nginx
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8.gz
```

What I did was force remove all those with `rm -rf` and then remove the existing symbolic links I found. After that, I was finally able to uninstall all the nginx-related packages you mentioned and actually re-install nginx.

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/nginx/1.18.0-6ubuntu11/nginx_1.18.0.orig.tar.gz
# extract
cd nginx_1.18.0.orig/nginx-1.18.0/
./configure
make
```

I installed from source (which I couldn't do before removing all the previous stuff) but it should be possible to use `apt-get install nginx` too.